# Is there a way to have hibernate and encrypted swap on nixos?

Tags: swap, disk-encryption, nixos

There's a way to get encrypted swap + hibernate on [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap). There's also a way to get encrypted swap on nixos (use randomEncryption.enable = true), and a way to make hibernate to swap. Is there a way to hibernate to encrypted swap?

Comment: As you probably noticed, `randomEncryption` is incompatible with hibernation. Have you tried the `encrypted.*` options? When I tried some time ago I got an error during the build, but perhaps it works now.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I don't see those options [in the source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/config/swap.nix).

Comment: It's in the `encrypted-devices` module: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/tasks/encrypted-devices.nix

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It looks like encrypted-devices needs a mounted partition to work (something in /etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix under filesystems) which swap isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, to use hibernate on encrypted swap you'll need to create a keyfile which is then used to unlock the LUKS-encrypted swap partition. This is in contrast to using a random encryption key, an option not compatible with hibernation.

Of course, with this approach the location of the keyfile matters. You're best bet is to also encrypt your root filesystem, and then put the keyfile there, (ex. /root/swap.key). In this case, you'll be prompted for the root filesystem password during boot, which then makes the keyfile available to the boot process, so it then can unlock the swap LUKS container and use the "unlocked" device as a swap device.

### Intructions

**NOTE:** *Consider these instructions a general guidance, rather than something you can simply copy-paste.*

After booting the installation media...

Create your partitions, LUKS containers, filesystems and mount them.

Create a keyfile: `dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/root/swap.key`

Create and LUKS container for your encrypted swap, using the keyfile.

Unlock the swap LUKS container, format it with `mkswap` and activate it with `swapon`.

Proceed with generating the NixOS configuration. So far, it's like a normal NixOS installation.

Create a keyfile: `dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/root/swap.key`

Move the `swapDevices` configuration from `/mnt/etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix` to `/mnt/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. Note: You'll need to repeat this step if you ever run `nixos-generate-config` again.

Edit `swapDevices` in `/mnt/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` to enable encryption. Here's an example:

```
swapDevices =
[ {
    device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/..."; #This is already done for you. Leave as-is.
    encrypted = {
      enable = true;
      keyFile = "/mnt-root/root/swap.key"; #Yes, /mnt-root is correct.
      label = "..."; The name used with `cryptsetup` when unlocking the LUKS container. It can be whatever you want, ex "luksswap".
      blkDev = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/[UUID of the LUKS partition]";
    };
  }
];
```

You can get the UUID of the LUKS partition with `lsblk -o name,uuid`.

Finally, `nixos-rebuild boot` and then reboot the system. Upon reboot NixOS will unlock the encrypted swap partition and activate it. If not, check `journalctl -b` for related errors.

Comment: Thanks for the method! There is just a typo, the option is `enable` not `enabled`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, @tobiasBora

Comment: I came here whether this approach would work if `/` is on ZFS, and swap is on LUKS, but https://nixos.wiki/wiki/ZFS#Known_issues links some ZFS issues that say that it might still not work safely: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/260#issuecomment-982142240 and https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/12842

Comment: Any idea if it is possible not to wait like 30 seconds when booting? Filled a bug here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/293294

Answer (score 0):

So, my approach was:

1. Create luks device with the same password as your main

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p1
   ```
2. Reboot to make sure the UUID updates correctly (not sure why it changes after first reboot)
3. Add configuration to mount the device in initrd:

   ```
   boot.initrd.luks.devices."swap".device = 
   "/dev/disk/by-uuid/936542de-2068-41b7-b804-741ec80a59c6";
   ```
4. Reboot to make sure device opens correctly. If passwords are the same, luks will ask for it only once and will try to open all devices with the same password.
5. Add plain config with UUID of opened volume, obtained with `blkid`:

   ```
     swapDevices =
       [{ device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/772a37e9-c010-4942-8f3d-b7f645092b02"; }];
   ```
6. Hibernate with `pm-hibernate`.